# Fetch data/posts from example.wordpress.com into android app

Tags: android, json, wordpress

I've a WordPress blog [http://stupidamigo.wordpress.com](http://stupidamigo.wordpress.com/), and I want to fetch data from my blog into my android app. How can I do it?

I read the answers regarding JSON Plugin but since this is a free WordPress account, so I can't install any plugins.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider using Html Parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)